# StartResolutionForResult is called over and over again

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location, android-gps

I have the problem that when I open my app and I call the permissions dialog using startResolutionForResult() and click no thanks there I get this dialog popping up over and over again until I click Om. How can I prevent this behavior so that when the user clicks No Thanks, the dialog disappears and only reappears when the user clicks a button ect?

The whole thing only happens in the onResume method. So I call showEnableLocationSetting() when I click on a button ect and then say no, everything works as it should

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        showEnableLocationSetting()
    }

 }


private fun showEnableLocationSetting() {
    this?.let {
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

        val task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(it)
            .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        task.addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            val states = response.locationSettingsStates
            if (states!!.isLocationPresent) {
                //Do something
            }
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                try {

                    // Called until the user presses Ok. No thanks will be ignored
                    e.startResolutionForResult(it,
                       200)
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) { }
            }
        }
      }
   }


  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (200) {
        RESULT_OK -> {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        RESULT_CANCELED->{
                return
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to modify the check in onResume() since this method will be called regardless of your choice of button in the system dialog (Since the app is getting into PAUSED state when the dialog is showing)